# What is the downside of replacing size_t with unsigned long

Tags: c++, integer

The library I am working on need to be used on both 32 and 64 bit machines; I have lots of compiler warnings because on 64bit machines `unsigned int != size_t`.

Is there any downside in replacing all `unsigned int`s and `size_t`s by 'unsigned long'? I appreciate it does not look very elegant, but, in out case, the memory is not too much of an issue... I am wondering if there is a possibility of any bugs/unwanted behaviour etc. created by such `replace all` operation (could you give examples)? Thanks.

Comment: If at some time specification of libraries changes and `size_t` gets signed, you'll be in a lot of trouble.

Comment: What is the probability of this happening? size_t is supposed to represent a memory address...

Comment: One downside is that on 64-bit Windows `size_t` is `unsigned long long` because `long` is just 32 bits (even in 64-bit mode).

Comment: Why not do the opposite and replace all relevant occurrences by `std::size_t`?

Comment: @YuccaV No, pointers (and `intptr_t`, in a way) are supposed to represent addresses. `size_t` represents object sizes, or indices into objects (arrays).

Comment: @Konrad well, sometimes we need longs

Comment: @YuccaV Besides what Angew said, maybe in the future size_t will became 128-bit and you'll end up with the same problem. The whole reason of `size_t` existence is for you not to worry about type used internally by the container.

Comment: @Spook ISO C requires `size_t` as an unsigned integer type. You will get almost nothing to work if it is changed to be signed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What warnings? The most obvious one I can think of is for a "narrowing conversion", that is to say you're assigning `size_t` to `unsigned int`, and getting a warning that information might be lost.

The main downside of replacing `size_t` with `unsigned long` is that `unsigned long` is not guaranteed to be large enough to contain every possible value of `size_t`, and on Windows 64 it is not large enough. So you might find that you still have warnings.

The proper fix is that if you assign a `size_t` to a variable (or data member), you should make sure that variable has a type large enough to contain any value of `size_t`. That's what the warning is all about. So you should not switch to `unsigned long`, you should switch those variables to `size_t`.

Conversely, if you have a variable that doesn't need to be big enough to hold any size, just big enough for `unsigned int`, then don't use `size_t` for it in the first place.

Both types (`size_t` and `unsigned int`) have valid uses, so any approach that indiscriminately replaces all use of them by some other type *must* be wrong :-) Actually, you could replace everything with `size_t` or `uintmax_t` and for *most* programs that would be OK. The exceptions are where the code relies on using an unsigned type of the same size as `int`, or whatever, such that a larger type breaks the code.

Answer (score 5):

The standard makes little guarantees about the sizes of types like `int` and `long`. `size_t` is guaranteed to be large enough to hold any object, and all `std` containers operate on `size_t`.

It's perfectly possible for a platform to define `long` as smaller than `size_t`, or have the size of `long` subject to compilation options, for example. To be safe, it's best to stick to `size_t`.

Another criterion to consider is that `size_t` carries a meaning - "this thing is used to store a size or an index." It makes the code slightly more self-documenting.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `size_t` in places where you *should* get a `size_t` and replace it with `unsigned long`, you will introduce new warnings.

example:

```
size_t count = some_vector.size();
```

Replace `size_t` with `unsigned long`, and (to the degree they are different) you will have introduced a new warning (because `some_vector.size()` returns a `size_t` - actually a `std:::vector<something>::size_type` but in practice it should evaluate to the same).

Comment: I might get more warning, true, but can upsizing induce a genuine trouble (e.g. bug)?

Comment: @YuccaV In any program which takes itself seriously, warnings are genuine trouble.

Comment: That depends on your code. If you have - for another example - calculated differences of offsets and compare them for being less than zero, with unsigned you may get negatives cast to unsigned, which should come somewhere near the max range the unsigned value of that type can represent (0x11111111 or similar). It depends on your codebase basically. Angew's point is valid though: your best bet is to set your compiler to have a zero tollerance for warnings (for gcc that's the `-Werror` option).

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem of assuming it's unsigned long when long is 8 bytes. then (unsigned int) -1 != (unsigned long) -1, the following code may have assertion failure.

```
unsigned int i = string::npos;
assert(i == string::npos);
```